# ngAnimate breaks existing ui.bootstrap.carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate

I have this current app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.router', 'com.2fdevs.videogular', 'com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls', 'com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay',
'com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster', 'com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.buffering', 'ngDraggable','angular-loading-bar', 'chart.js', 'angularSpinner'])
```

and I include the needed javascript files in my index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

With this, the carousel is working at least, there is no transition animation, but if I click on the arrow it switches to the next one.

then I added the angular-animate to the index.html:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and ngAnimate to the app.js as dependency.

But this break the carousel. With this, the carousel won't go forward on its own and a click on the arrow will do nothing. I do not see any errors in the console and not at all why this is not working. Am I missing some css stuff or what?

Comment: Check the ui-bootstrap issue tracker. There were breaking changes in `ngAnimate` in angular 1.4 that caused problems with existing animations. Some I know were fixed in last release `0.13.1` which you are using  that helped one of my projects

Comment: you are right, it seems like ui.bootstrap does not support angular 1.4, I used 1.3.17 and there the animation works.
Seems like I have to either downgrade or wait for 0.14 (it seems they support it by then)

Comment: There is a 0.13.3 version for Bootstrap UI, you might want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

May be a little late here, but there is a solution to this. Make a directive which essentially disables ng-animate:

```
app.directive('disableAnimation', function ($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $attrs.$observe('disableAnimation', function (value) {
                $animate.enabled(!value, $element);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then add attribute "disable-animation='true'" to your carousel tag. This solution was suggested by another user on a different question. I'm trying desperately to find him and give him the credit he deserves, I'll make an edit if I locate it.