# Angular Bootstrap Carousel Not Pause On Hover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to prevent my carousel from stopping when the mouse is over the slides. I've tried to add pause=false in the uib-carousel directive as I have read somewhere else however that doesn't work. I'm also inspecting the element but can't really find where can I set that option (if that's possible).

I have also seen people adding to the .carousel class the pause=false and then I tried to add to add the CSS without success as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js and looks like there is an attribute for that directive called "no-pause". I will give that a go!

Comment: That has worked and I got the carousel moving all the time

Answer (score 0):

I would first confirm ngAnimate is not interfering with the carousel in any way. To accomplish this, simply follow the instructions in this post: [ngAnimate breaks existing ui.bootstrap.carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161787/nganimate-breaks-existing-ui-bootstrap-carousel)

Comment: I don't think it does. I've read the post and will try the disable-animation attribute. However I still think the behavior of the carrousel is correct. My problem is how to prevent it from stopping when the mouse enters and hovers over the images. That's an existing feature but I can't see the toggle to disable it. I'm using angular 1.4.8 and angular bootstrap 0.14.3. There isn't much documentation about that on their website either